# Filter Array For IDs Existing in Another Array with Ruby on Rails/Mongo

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I need to compare the 2 arrays declared here to return records that exist only in the filtered_apps array. I am using the contents of previous_apps array to see if an ID in the record exists in filtered_apps array. I will be outputting the results to a CSV and displaying records that exist in both arrays to the console.

My question is this: How do I get the records that only exist in filtered_apps? Easiest for me would be to put those unique records into a new array to work with on the csv.

```
start_date = Date.parse("2022-02-05")
end_date   = Date.parse("2022-05-17")
valid_year = start_date.year
dupe_apps = []
uniq_apps = []

# Finding applications that meet my criteria:
filtered_apps = FinancialAssistance::Application.where(
    :is_requesting_info_in_mail => true, 
    :aasm_state => "determined",
    :submitted_at => {
        "$exists" => true, 
        "$gte" => start_date, 
        "$lte" => end_date })

# Finding applications that I want to compare against filtered_apps
previous_apps = FinancialAssistance::Application.where(
    is_requesting_info_in_mail: true,
    :submitted_at => {
        "$exists" => true, 
        "$gte" => valid_year })

# I'm using this to pull the ID that I'm using for comparison just to make the comparison lighter by only storing the family_id
previous_apps.each do |y|    
    previous_apps_array << y.family_id
end

# This is where I'm doing my comparison and it is not working.
filtered_apps.each do |app|
    if app.family_id.in?(previous_apps_array) == false
                then @non_dupe_apps << app
            else "No duplicate found for application #{app.hbx_id}"
            end
        end
    end
```

So what am I doing wrong in the last code section?

Comment: Also forgot to mention, I'm on ruby 2.5.9 so some of the best tools to do this aren't in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check your original method first (I fixed the indentation to make it clearer). There's quite a few issues with it:

```rb
filtered_apps.each do |app|
    if app.family_id.in?(previous_apps_array) == false
        # Where is "@non_dupe_apps" declared? It isn't anywhere in your example...
        # Also, "then" is not necessary unless you want a one-line if-statement
        then @non_dupe_apps << app

    # This doesn't do anything, it's just a string
    # You need to use "p" or "puts" to output something to the console
    # Note that the "else" is also only triggered when duplicates WERE found...
    else "No duplicate found for application #{app.hbx_id}"
        end # Extra "end" here, this will mess things up
    end
end
```

Also, you haven't declared `previous_apps_array` anywhere in your example, you just start adding to it out of nowhere.

Getting the difference between 2 arrays is dead easy in Ruby: just use `-`!

```rb
uniq_apps = filtered_apps - previous_apps
```

You can also do this with ActiveRecord results, since they are just arrays of ActiveRecord objects. However, this doesn't help if you specifically need to compare results using the `family_id` column.

**TIP:** Getting the values of only a specific column/columns from your database is probably best done with the `pluck` or `select` method if you don't need to store any other data about those objects. With `pluck`, you only get an array of values in the result, not the full objects. `select` works a bit differently and returns ActiveRecord objects, but filters out everything but the selected columns. `select` is usually better in nested queries, since it doesn't trigger a separate query when used as a part of another query, while `pluck` always triggers one.

```rb
# Querying straight from the database
# This is what I would recommend, but it doesn't print the values of duplicates
uniq_apps = filtered_apps.where.not(family_id: previous_apps.select(:family_id))
```

I highly recommend getting really familiar with at least `filter/select`, and `map` out of the basic array methods. They make things like this way easier. [The Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.9/Array.html) are a great place to learn about them and others. A very simple example of doing a similar thing to what you explained in your question with `filter/select` on 2 arrays would be something like this:

```rb
arr = [1, 2, 3]
full_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

unique_numbers = full_arr.filter do |num|
    if arr.include?(num)
        puts "Duplicates were found for #{num}"
        false
    else
        true
    end
end

# Duplicates were found for 1
# Duplicates were found for 2
# Duplicates were found for 3
=> [4, 5]
```

**NOTE:** The OP is working with `ruby 2.5.9`, where `filter` is not yet available as an array method ([it was introduced in 2.6.3](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Array/filter)). However, `filter` is just an alias for `select`, which can be found on earlier versions of Ruby, so they can be used interchangeably. Personally, I prefer using `filter` because, as seen above, `select` is already used in other methods, and `filter` is also the more common term in other programming languages I usually work with. Of course when both are available, it doesn't really matter which one you use, as long as you keep it consistent.

Comment: Thanks!! Apologies for my code looking like it does. My original report was working except it kept returning some dupes in it, so I've been copy/pasting bits and pieces trying to work on it, and the result is that messiness. 

I'll try this and see how it works. From what I read just now, I see where at least one fault in my logic was. This post was my hail mary, so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My last answer did, in fact, not work.

Here is the code all nice and working.

It turns out the issue was that when comparing family_id from the set of records I forgot that the looped record was a part of the set, so it would return it, too. I added a check for the ID of the array to match the looped record and bob's your uncle.

I added the pass and reject arrays so I could check my work instead of downloading a csv every time. Leaving them in mostly because I'm scared to change anything else.

```
    start_date    =  Date.parse(date_from)
    end_date      =  Date.parse(date_to)
    valid_year    =  start_date.year
    date_range    =  (start_date)..(end_date)
    comparison_apps =  FinancialAssistance::Application.by_year(start_date.year).where(
        aasm_state:'determined',
        is_requesting_voter_registration_application_in_mail:true)

apps = FinancialAssistance::Application.where(
        :is_requesting_voter_registration_application_in_mail => true, 
        :submitted_at => date_range).uniq{ |n| n.family_id}

        @pass_array   = []
        @reject_array = []
        apps.each do |app|
            family = app.family
            app_id = app.id
            previous_apps = comparison_apps.where(family_id:family.id,:id.ne => app.id)

            if previous_apps.count > 0
                @reject_array << app
                puts "\e[32mApplicant hbx id \e[31m#{app.primary_applicant.person_hbx_id}\e[32m in family ID \e[31m#{family.id}\e[32m has registered to vote in a previous application.\e[0m"
            else
                <csv fields here>
        
                csv << [csv fields here]
            end
        end
```

Basically, I pulled the applications into the app variable array, then filtered them by the family_id field in each record.

I had to do this because the issue at the bottom of everything was that there were records present in app that were themselves duplicates, only submitted a few days apart. Since I went on the assumption that the initial app array would be all unique, I thought the duplicates that were included were due to the rest of the code not filtering correctly.

I then use the uniq_apps array to filter through and look for matches in uniq_apps.each do, and when it finds a duplicate, it adds it to the previous_applications array inside the loop. Since this array resets each go-round, if it ever has more than 0 records in it, the app gets called out as being submitted already. Otherwise, it goes to my csv report.

Thanks for the help on this, it really got my brain thinking in another direction that I needed to. It also helped improve the code even though the issue was at the very beginning.

Comment: Ah yes, seems that at least `filter` is slightly newer Ruby syntax than your version of `2.5.9`, I missed that! It's just an alias for `select` though, which is [okay in Ruby 2.5.9](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.9/Array.html#method-i-select). I'll update my answer to work for `2.5.9`!

But good to hear you got it working!  Looks pretty good to me what you're doing here. Only thing is that running `where` to get the `previous_applications` on every iteration might get expensive, since it triggers a database query every time (N+1 queries), so I'd swap that out for `select` or something else.

Comment: What I would recommend here is to do a `group_by(&:family_id)` on `previous_apps` before the loop. That should be much faster than having to filter the results on each iteration, and grouping by family seems to be the goal in your example anyway. More info about `group_by` can be found in [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.9/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). Note that on some iterations of the loop you might get `nil` (when the family doesn't have votes), so you'll have to do `grouped_results[app.family_id].try(:count) || 0` or similar to avoid calling `count` on `nil`.

Comment: So I was actually just moments ago able to get it to work. I was getting duplicates because I was comparing the app in the loop to the list of apps, which the looped app would most certainly be a part of. That is where the leak was happening. I also rewrote it to be less hectic and more planned out. See my answer below.